# automatic upload file path in website using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, file-upload, sendkeys

I am trying to upload file from my machine by giving file path into field2. But its not working.I am using VBA excel.Below is the screenshot of that website page.Please help. Thanks in advance .

#### website screenshot1

[image: website screenshot1]

#### website screenshot2

[image: website screenshot2]

**Html code for fileuploader**

<'input id="field2" title="Upload file" maxlength="30" size="25" name="field2" value="Select a File" type="File">

**Below is my VBA code**

```
objIE.document.getElementById("activityText").Value = " this is for activity textbox" 
objIE.document.getElementById("field1").Value = " this is for description text box" 
'for below click event, file upload popup is coming but unable put file path
objIE.document.getElementById("field2").Click
 
objIE.document.all.field2.Focus()

Set objShell = CreateObject(Wscript.Shell)

objShell.SendKeys ("C:\User\filename.zip")
```

Comment: Hi :). Can you please elaborate on where it is failing?  Is it erroring out at some point? Is it failing to hit upload? Is it failing to `sendkeys` your file path?  Please help by adding the details and maybe I [or someone else] can better assist you.

Comment: @Busse: I am new in VBA. I am unable to upload a file from my machine using this code. Do not which part is not working. Till "Browse" button click event its working after that unable to put file path and unable to click open button. Please see my screenshot